# matlab - two variables least squares function approximation

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, least-squares

I have a function of two variables of the type: y = f(x1,x2) to be approximated and I would like to use least squares method to do it.

Polyval and Polyfit work with two-dimensional function, here I need to solve a three-dimensional function.

Thanks in advance.

G.B.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497448/curve-fitting-without-toolbox

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it in this way

A = [x1.^2,x1.*x2,x2.^2,x1,x2,ones(length(x1),1)];
c=A\y;

yEval = c(1)*x1.^2+c(2)*x1.*x2+c(3)*x2.^2+c(4)*x1+c(5)*x2+c(6);

Thanks anyway for your help.

Regards,
G.B.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your function, it looks like you're using a full quadratic response surface to fit against.
You could use x2fx function to generate all the terms.  It's nothing groundbreaking here, but it might be a little cleaner.  You could also use it to do not just OLS fitting, but also use the robust methods.
Here's some code I've written:

```
% set up terms for the variables, linear, quadratic, interactive, and constant
paramVEcomponents= x2fx([MAPkpa,RPM],'quadratic');
% robust fit using a Talwar weighting function
[coefs,robuststats]= robustfit(paramVEcomponents(2:6),(CAM2.*TEMPd./MAPkpa),'talwar');
% generating points for all the data we have based on the new parameters of the response surface
GMVEhat= paramVEcomponents * coefs;
```

Comment: I think this answer requires the statistics toolbox