# Generate Equation from 3D surf Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, equation, trend

I am wondering if anyone knows (or is it possible?) how to generate a trend equation from a 3D surf plot from Matlab? I understand that we can create trendline for 2D plots (linear and nonlinear) and show its equation, but how about 3D plot? Can we create something like:

z = ax + by?

Regards
Kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the curve fitting toolbox you can fit 3D surfaces using cftool as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/surface-fitting.html).

Here's an example:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100);
X = reshape(X,numel(X),1);
Y = reshape(Y,numel(Y),1);
Z = 3*X+4*Y;
plot3(X,Y,Z)

f = fit([X, Y], Z, 'poly11');
coeffvalues(f)
```

Comment: hi, I have plotted the surface plot using some data (without equation). Now I am actually looking forward to use Matlab to generate the equation for me from the plot itself. The Basic Fitting is grayed out (disabled) from the Tools.

Comment: Basic fitting won't work for surfaces. You can type ver at the command prompt to find out if you have the curve fitting box. If not, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497448/curve-fitting-without-toolbox

Comment: I have curve fitting toolbox in my Matlab. But is it possible to use it and generate the equation I want in the form of z = ax + by?

Comment: Yes. I've added an example. There's more information in the link I included.

Comment: I used Surface Fitting Tool (sftool) instead for 3D equation generation. This is the results I got from your example:

Comment: Linear model Poly43:
     f(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p30*x^3 + p21*x^2*y 
                    + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3 + p40*x^4 + p31*x^3*y + p22*x^2*y^2 
                    + p13*x*y^3

Comment: `Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p00 = -1.837e-012  (-2.372e-012, -1.302e-012)
       p10 =           3  (3, 3)
       p01 =           4  (4, 4)
       p20 = -1.283e-014  (-1.419e-014, -1.148e-014)
       p11 = -1.275e-015  (-2.334e-015, -2.173e-016)
       p02 = -4.633e-016  (-1.162e-015, 2.357e-016)
       p30 =  1.306e-016  (1.123e-016, 1.49e-016)
       p21 =  1.855e-017  (4.498e-018, 3.261e-017)
       p12 =  4.552e-018  (-9.503e-018, 1.861e-017)
       p03 =  1.857e-018  (-2.614e-018, 6.328e-018)
       p40 = -3.571e-019  (-4.452e-019, -2.689e-019)
`

Comment: `    p31 = -1.011e-019  (-1.78e-019, -2.427e-020)
       p22 = -4.543e-020  (-1.209e-019, 3.004e-020)
       p13 =  1.747e-020  (-5.941e-020, 9.434e-020)`

Comment: `Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 4.564e-020
  R-square: 1
  Adjusted R-square: 1
  RMSE: 2.138e-012`