# curve-fitting for linear and exponential function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of data which, when plotted, looks wave.I need to determine the best fitting (linear and exponential) for these data and find the value of lambda 1,lambda 2 and tau in this function ((L=lambda 1*t+lambda 2*(1-exp(-t/tau).
Some friends advice my to use((polyfit)) but I couldn't understanding the applicability of the command after reading the help file and searching in Google. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

my attempt was as following:

```
%% data 1

file1 = dlmread('outfile_rate_add0.5_depGDP_GTP0.1.txt');
t1      = file1 (:,1);
d1      = file1 (:,2);

% Then call plot()

plot(t1, d1, 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 15);
% Then get a fit

coeffs1 = polyfit(t1, d1, 1)
% Get fitted values
fittedX1 = linspace(min(t1), max(t1), 1001);
fittedY1 = polyval(coeffs1, fittedX1);
% Plot the fitted line
hold on;
plot(fittedX1, fittedY1, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 3);
hold off
hleg = legend('Data','lam*t + c','Location','northEast');

 grid on; 
 title('Line fitting ','fontsize',13,'fontweight','b','color','k')
 xlabel('Time ms','fontsize',13,'fontweight','b','color','k');
 ylabel('Averge length','fontsize',13,'fontweight','b','color','k');
```

Comment: silly question: do you have the curve fitting toolbox?

Comment: NO, I don't have this book Benoit_11. If you have it could you send it to me.

Comment: Actually it's not a book but a Toolbox that you can purchase from The Mathworks and run with Matlab; there are a few functions that would be useful to you. That's fine though there should be a workaround without this Toolbox.

Comment: So what is your question? You showed the code but you did not say what is wrong with what comes out of it.

Comment: The code looks fine to me, although here `coeffs1 = polyfit(t1, d1, 1)` you ask for a polynomial of degree one (ie straight line) to be fitted which will clearly not give you very good fit if the data has a wave pattern.

Comment: In the above code. I fitted the data with the line (lambda 1*t +c) only. I want to fit the data with the function (L=lambda 1*t+lambda 2*(1-exp(-t/tau) and find the value of lambda 1 , lambda 2 and tau. I tried to use polyfit but it does not useful. How can I do that??

Comment: Of course it is not useful since `L` is not a polynomial. `Polyfit` only fits functions of the form `y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + ...`. I thought the data were generated by `L` and now you want to fit a polynomial function in it. So if I understand your problem correctly it is quite complex. I do not know how to do that easily.

Comment: These two links might help you. If your matlab installation has the fitting toolbox then you can use the `fit` function, the example "fit a curve defined by a file" at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/fit.html does what you want. If you do not have the toolbox then this question is asking the same as you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497448/curve-fitting-without-toolbox

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the Optimization toolbox, you can formulate this problem, such that it can be solved with fminsearch(). Here is how it can be done:
The parameter to optimize (lambda1, lambda2 and tau) are stored in one parameter-vector, which will be used by the fit_function, which is the function that you proposed.

```
function main

% some data
t = sort(rand(50,1)*10);
lambda1 = 0.5;
lambda2 = 1;
tau = 2.0;
par = [lambda1, lambda2, tau];
y = fit_function(t, par) + (rand(size(t))-0.5)*0.2;

par0 = [1,2,3]; % initial guess
par_fit = fminsearch(@objFun, par0);

% nested objective function, this one will be minimized
function e = objFun(par)
    yfitted = fit_function(t, par);
    e = sum((yfitted-y).^2);
end

% plotting some results
figure
plot(t,fit_function(t,par),'k-')
hold on
plot(t,y,'ko')
plot(t,fit_function(t,par_fit),'rx-')
legend('original','noisy','optimization')
par
par_fit

end

function yfitted = fit_function(t, par)
% y = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau))
    lambda1 = par(1);
    lambda2 = par(2);
    tau = par(3);
    yfitted = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau)); 
end
```

The result looks like this:
[image]
The parameters i used for the unnoisy data and the parameters which came out of the optimization are like this

```
par =

    0.5000    1.0000    2.0000


par_fit =

    0.4949    1.0433    2.1792
```

Best, Nras.

**Update for your use-case**

```
function main
%% ----- DATA ----- 
file1 = dlmread('outfile_rate_add0.5_depGDP_GTP0.1.txt');
t = file1(:,1);
y = file1(:,2);

%% ----- OPTIMIZATION ----- 
par0 = [1,2,3]; % initial guess <--- Here you have to make a good guess 
par_fit = fminsearch(@objFun, par0);

%% ----- OBJECTIVE FUNCTION (will be minimized) ----- 
function e = objFun(par)
    yfitted = fit_function(t, par); % result of model function with current parameter
    e = sum((yfitted-y).^2); % minimize squared distance between model and observation
end

%% ----- VSIUALIZING RESULTS ----- %
figure
plot(t,y,'ko')
hold on
plot(t,fit_function(t,par_fit),'rx-')
legend('original','optimization')
end

%% ----- MODEL FUNCTION ----- %
function yfitted = fit_function(t, par)
% the model function reads as:  y = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau))
    lambda1 = par(1);
    lambda2 = par(2);
    tau = par(3);
    yfitted = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau)); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nras....I have an anonymous Function> I do not know the value of lambda1, lambda2 and tau

Comment: @Abdulrahman Well that is the problem, if you knew the values for lambda1, lambda2 and tau, then you would not have to make an optimization. I just set some values for lambda1, lambda2 and tau to generate some data, but you already have some data.  You just need to give an initial guess `par0` and the optimizer will try to get an optimal solution from there.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Do you mean I have to set par0=[1,2,3];and create my function yfitted = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau));. In fact,I get lost

Comment: You just have to replace the part below the line `% some data` with your own data, which is stored in `t1` and `d1`. Since i did not have access to that data, i created my own data in that section and called it `t` and `y`, which was more intuitive. You can play around using different intitial gueses for `par0`, yes. They could be of competely different order of magnitude for your real data.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation with me,could you write the code according to my data. I think there are many variable need to change.

Comment: f=dlmread();t = file1 (:,1);
d= file1 (:,2);
y = fit_function(t, d) ;
par0 = [1,2,3]; % initial guess
par_fit = fminsearch(@objFun, par0);
function e = objFun(d)
    yfitted = fit_function(t, d);
    e = sum((yfitted-y).^2);
end
% plotting some results
figure
plot(t,fit_function(t,d),'k-')
hold on
plot(t,y,'ko')
plot(t,fit_function(t,par_fit),'rx-')
legend('original','noisy','optimization')
d;
par_fit
end
function yfitted = fit_function(t, d)
% y = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau))
    lambda1 = d(1);
    lambda2 = d(2);
    tau = d(3);
    yfitted = lambda1*t + lambda2*(1-exp(-t/tau)); 
end

Comment: The 6 lines below my `% some data` comment reduce to `file1 = dlmread(...); t = file1(:,1); y = file1(:,2)` is all you really need. Then the code should find an optimum with respect your initial guess `par0` which you have to adjust a little.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. If I did as you said I have to delete(( par = [lambda1, lambda2, tau];)) and in next section                                          % nested objective function, this one will be minimized
function e = objFun(par)
    yfitted = fit_function(t, par);
    e = sum((yfitted-y).^2);
end  (( par)) what have to be

Comment: Hey, i am not sure if i understand, nor am i sure if we should discuss this here. In the nested objFun, `par`is a variable, you do not need to define `par = [lambda1, lambda2, tau]` before that, just the `par0 = [...]`, as this variable will be handed over to the function and you will get back the result as optimized parameters `par_fit`. In the plotting part, this line `plot(t,fit_function(t,par),'k-')` can be omitted. Good Luck.

Comment: @Abdulrahman I edited my original answer and added an updated and deeply explained version of my code, such that it fits to your use case. You should just let it run and get a result. You might have to use different initial guesses `par0`, as i have no idea what they could be for your real data. That is the best i can do for you.